# WPF:The coordinate of image is retrieved incorrectly when alignment is center

Tags: wpf, image, alignment, transform, center

I settle an image control on grid in WPF :

```
<Window x:Class="Window.PhotoViewer"
    Title="PhotoViewer" Height="768" Width="1024" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">


<Grid Name="ViewerGrid">
    <Image Name="imageBox" Width="980" Height="615" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" Stretch="None" />
</Grid>
```

I use function **TransformToAncestor** to get the position of imageBox :

```
  Point leftTop = imageBox.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(-imageBox.ActualWidth/2, -imageBox.ActualHeight/2));
  Point rightButtom = imageBox.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(imageBox.ActualWidth/2, imageBox.ActualHeight/2));
```

then I draw a line to connect those two points :

```
Line line = new Line();
line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.OrangeRed;
line.X1 = leftTop.X;
line.Y1 = leftTop.Y;
line.X2 = rightButtom.X;
line.Y2 = rightButtom.Y;
line.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
line.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
line.StrokeThickness = 5;
ViewerGrid.Children.Add(line);
```

The result is incorrectly. How to obtain the correct position of controller when alignment is **center** ?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but i guess the following XAML should do the job without any TransformToAncestor calls:

```
<Grid Name="ViewerGrid">
    <Image Name="imageBox" Width="980" Height="615" Stretch="None"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" />

    <Line HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, ElementName=imageBox}"
          VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalAlignment, ElementName=imageBox}"
          Margin="{Binding Margin, ElementName=imageBox}"
          X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=imageBox}"
          Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=imageBox}"
          Stroke="OrangeRed" StrokeThickness="5"/>
</Grid>
```

or, even simpler, Image and Line in another Grid that takes the HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment and Margin properties:

```
<Grid Name="ViewerGrid">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <Image Name="imageBox" Width="980" Height="615" Stretch="None"/>
        <Line X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=imageBox}"
              Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=imageBox}"
              Stroke="OrangeRed" StrokeThickness="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If for some reason you need to go with TransformToAncenstor, i guess you would have to get the image box like this:

```
var transform = imageBox.TransformToAncestor(this);
Point topLeft = transform.Transform(new Point());
Point bottomRight = transform.Transform(new Point(imageBox.ActualWidth, imageBox.ActualHeight));
```

And you would have to set `HorizontalAlignment.Left` and `VerticalAlignment.Top` on the Line control.